# how to call a function when app destroy in ionic 3 app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

i want to call a function when ionic 3 app destroy ..
 if anyone having idea about this please help me to find out the right solution

THANKS

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow. You need to post more context and your current code implementation that is relevant to your question to get help. Otherwise its too vague and unclear.

Comment: you can check [platform](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/) pause and resume events.

Answer (score 1):

In your component that you want to test I would suggest you put these in to see if any of the Life Cycle Hooks can give you what you need.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad');
}
ionViewWillEnter() {
    console.log('ionViewWillEnter');
}
ionViewDidEnter() {
    console.log('ionViewDidEnter');
}
ionViewWillLeave() {
    console.log('ionViewWillLeave');
}
ionViewDidLeave() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLeave');
}
ionViewWillUnload() {
    console.log('ionViewWillUnload');
}
ionViewCanEnter() {
    console.log('ionViewCanEnter');
}
ionViewCanLeave() {
    console.log('ionViewCanLeave');
}
```

I would refer to [ViewController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/ViewController/)

and also [NavController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/)